# Wrong results with dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, numerical-methods

I am trying to find out the Lagrange's Interpolation with the program. I have solved it using arrays but when using dynamic memory allocation, the program is giving me garbage result.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define SIZE 100

int main()
{
    float *x,*y;
    float value = 0,ask,temp;
    int i,j,n;
    printf("Enter size");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    x = (float*)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
    y = (float*)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
    for(i = 0; i < n;i++)
    {
            printf("x[%d]: ",i);
            scanf("%f",(x+i));
            printf("y[%d]: ",i);
            scanf("%f",(y+i));
    }
    printf("Enter value to find");
    scanf("%f",&ask); //cin >> ask;
    for(i = 0; i < n;i++)
    {
        temp = 1;
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(i != j)
            {
                temp = temp * (ask-(*(x+i))/(*(x+i)-*(x+j)));
            }
        }
        value = value + temp * *(y+i);
    }
    printf("%f",value); 
}
```

Comment: Your code would be easier to read if instead of writing `*(x+i)` you just wrote `x[i]`, which is completely equivalent.  Similarly for `*(y+i)` vs. `y[i]`.  They are again equivalent.

Comment: try `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: Have you done basic debugging? By running your program in a debugger and looking at the variable values at each stage to see if they are what you expect and where things start going wrong? Or even basic `printf` debug statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `#include <stdlib.h>`, since that is the header that declares functions that perform dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()`, etc).

You will find, assuming you use a C compiler and not a C++ compiler, that the type conversions on the `malloc()` calls are not required.

```
x = (float*)malloc(n*sizeof(float));      /*   (float *) is unnecessary */
```

The problem is that, without `stdlib.h`, the compiler assumes `malloc()` returns an `int`.   The type conversion might allow the code to compile without `stdlib.h`, but the result is subsequent usage of the `malloc()`d pointer will have undefined behaviour, since the pointer does not necessarily survive the round trip (being converted to `int` and then back).

If you are using a C++ compiler, then the `(float *)` type conversion AND `#include <stdlib.h>` are BOTH required to avoid undefined behaviour.